# On calling partail view from a view, throwing validation error twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

**I have a aspx page in my view, which calls a partial view,**

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "MyReport", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "myform", autocomplete = "off" }))
   {%>
    <%
       Html.RenderPartial("_Form");%>    
 <% } %>
```

**partial view is**

```
    <div>
        <%=Html.ValidationSummary()%>    
    </div>    
    <div class="fieldRow">    
        <span class="fieldCell threeCol">    
            <label for="schedule.SavedReportName">   
                Name<span class="requiredField">*</span>    
            </label>   
        <%=Html.TextBox("schedule.SavedReportName", ViewData.Model.SavedReportName, new {style = "width:516px;"})%>    
        </span>   
    </div>
```

**My model has this property**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]

[StringLength(60, ErrorMessage = "Maximum 60")]
public string SavedReportName { get; set; }
```

The problem I am getting is, I am able to see string length validation error twice.
What might be the problem?

Comment: are you using ajax validations?

Comment: Thanks for reply,
We are not using any ajax validations..

Comment: One more point, We are using IDataErrorInfo interface to hold error messages. Is that going to do any difference?